# unable to implement tooltip view in editext

Tags: android

[image]

I need to implement this tooltip view like iphone in android code

I refer the link below for editext focus

[EditText with an helpper tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817620/edittext-with-an-helpper-tooltip)

and for pop up

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Please help me for this

Comment: If you want to assist user for input you can use `android:hint` in `EditText` tag in xml. If you want to use tooltip and don't want to reinvent the wheel you can use this :https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest instead of developing your own tooltip, why don't you use some predefined lib and modify it.

here is good example which can fulfil your requirement

[Here on GitHub](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)

[image]

I hope this will help you.